# Will a Lisp dialect that works with Apache Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, clojure, lisp

Is there an application server like Apache Tomcat that I can use with a Lisp like web language?

I've been playing a little bit with Arc/Anarki and Clojure lately.  But what I really miss is something like mod_arc or mod_clojure for Apache.  What I really miss is good Apache integration for a Lispy web language.

Both Arc and Clojure use their own built in webserver that you launch within your code.  I want all the functionality, resiliency and scalability that Apache httpd gives me.  Is anyone working on an Apache module for Arc or Clojure?  Is there another Lisp like language that I can use with Apache?

I come from a background in PHP and Perl.  But also have lots of experience in C and /bin/sh.  Since when I started writing web apps I was using cgi-bin and stdin to C binaries.

Answer (score 7):

You can set up a Clojure/Java HTTP server (Jetty, etc.) running on some port, then use Apache's [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) to forward certain requests from Apache to Clojure on that port.  Something like this in your Apache configs:

```
    ProxyPass /static !
    ProxyPass /cgi-bin !
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

So Apache will send every request to your Clojure app on port 8080 except requests to things in `/static` and `/cgi-bin`, which Apache will handle itself.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer. I might give this a try just as an experiment.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe [mod_lisp](http://www.fractalconcept.com/asp/DXOr/sdataQkvOnIhYS7rwDM==/sdataQuvY9x3g$ecX) would work?

Answer (score 6):

[Hunchentoot](http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/), a web server in/for Common Lisp, can also be used behind Apache, through mod_lisp2.

Comment: This is pretty much the standard solution for Lisp web deployment; Hunchentoot running the app with Apache/Nginx/Lighttp/what-have-you out front handling the static content/SSL certs.

Answer (score 6):

Using [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) and [Compojure](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Compojure), you can generate WAR-archives that can be deployed in pretty much any Java EE-webserver (Jetty, Tomcat etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Clojure is a JVM language, so you should be able to set it up pretty much like any other Java app.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use CGI?